# Plot $2|z|=|z-2|$ over the complex plain

Tags: complex-analysis

I was given a home work to Sketch $2|z|=|z-2|$ on the complex plane.I tried to simplify and found out that the last expression was $3x^2+3y^2+4x-4$. However I don't know how to sketch this on the complex plane and how I can describe the set of points

Comment: Where did the equals sign go during your simplification?

Comment: In words, $2|z|=|z-2|$ says that the distance from $z$ to $2$ (on the real axis) is twice the distance from $z$ to $0$. So your sketch will be symmetric around the line through $0$ and $2$ (i.e. the real axis). Can you find real numbers satisfying the equation? Numbers on the imaginary axis? (There are two of each.)

Comment: Write It as $ x^2+y^2+\frac{4}{3}x-\frac43=0$ and By Completing the square we Obtain $\Big(x+\frac23 \Big)^2+y^2=\frac{16}{9}$ Which represents a circle with centre at $\Big(-\frac23 ,0 \Big)$ and Radius $\frac {4}{3}$.

Comment: @user1055 For future reference, if I had seen your analysis as an answer, rather than a comment, then I would have upvoted your answer, just as I upvoted your comment.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for your suggestion. I will surely write these type of comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $2|z| = |z - 2|$ represents the locus of points in the complex plane such that the distance from $(2,0) = 2 + 0i$ is twice the distance from the origin.  So one obvious example of such a point would be $z = 2/3$, since the distance from the origin is $2/3$ and the distance from $2$ is $2 - 2/3 = 4/3$.

Another (slightly less) obvious example would be $z = -2$, since its distance to the origin is $2$, but the distance to $2$ is $4$.

Since you found an equation $3x^2 + 3y^2 + 4x - 4$, where $x$ is the real part of $z$ and $y$ the imaginary part (i.e., $z = x + iy$), what happens when you plug in $(x,y) = (2/3, 0)$?  What happens when you plug in $(x,y) = (-2, 0)$?  Why do both of these choices give you $0$ for this expression?

Now, what does the equation $$3x^2 + 3y^2 + 4x - 4 = 0$$ correspond to in the Cartesian coordinate plane?  What curve does it look like?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$2|z|=|z-2| \Leftrightarrow \\
4|z|^2 = |z-2|^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
4z \bar{z}= (z-2)(\bar{z}-2) = z \bar{z}-2z -2 \bar{z}+4 \Leftrightarrow \\
3z \bar{z} +2z +2 \bar{z}-4 =0 \Leftrightarrow \\
9z \bar{z} +6z +6 \bar{z}-12 =0\Leftrightarrow \\
(3z+2)(3 \bar{z}+2)=8\Leftrightarrow \\
|3z+2|^2=8
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\phi(z) = {z-2 \over 2z}$ is a Möbius transformation and you are looking for $\{ z | |\phi(z)|=1 \} = \phi^{-1}(\partial B(0,1))$.

Since the inverse of a Möbius transformation is a Möbius transformation, and Möbius transformations transform circles into circles, we see that the set in question is a circle.

It is simple to verify that $-2, {2 \over 3}$ and ${2 \over \sqrt{3}}i$ are in this locus and from these three points we can easily plot the set.

Comment: Why the down (& delete) votes? This shows that the set of points is a circle from which it is straigforward to plot.